# How Do I Find My DNS Server IP Address?

Tags: windows-10, dns

My Router is a Huawei E5180s-22 LTE Cube. My system is Windows 10.
`ipconfig` and `nslookup` both give me "192.168.8.1" as DNS server which is the same as my default gateway. I have taken a look at the router's web interface, and there was no  apparent way to determine the DNS server through it. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In most domestic setups, your default gateway **is** your DNS server.

Consumer all-in-one modem/routers are done this way to keep things simple for people who wouldn't even know where to look, let alone why.  DHCP makes sure this is seamless for most people.
The router itself will make its requests to your ISP, then cache those locally.

There is almost no reason to ever change it, unless your ISP has [usually temporary] issues.

You **can** change it from your own computer [Adaptor Properties], you don't need to change it on the router - but again, unless you have good reason to, don't.

Comment: `There is almost no reason to ever change it,` uh, yes there is. ISP DNS is really slow. If you set it to use google dns, then it is already quite a bit faster, and if you use OpenDNS, 1.1.1.1 and 1.0.0.1, then you get the fastest DNS currently possible.

Comment: Yeah, people keep insisting that. I've never seen any improvement by changing mine, only ever a worse service. OpenDNS, in fact, used to be hideously slow from here, because it was being served from Asia. I understand they've spread out since, but I just don't get the point.

Comment: Strange, I've changed to it, and my internet has become snappier. Google DNS was already a bit faster than my ISP's DNS, but with OpenDNS, the initial response is even snappier. But we're talking milliseconds here.

Comment: I've just tested again, Google & Open... both just hideously slow. This page wouldn't even load, though the other 20 or so SE tabs did eventually refresh. They're just no good at all for me, London UK. I just use Virgin Media's own & it's fast. [One more experiment, I'll change it at the router...]

Comment: It's quicker if I set it on the router, but not enough to make me want to swap to it permanently.

Comment: @LPChip - `1.1.1.1` is Cloudflare's DNS not OpenDNS.  OpenDNS has an entirely different DNS IPv4 address.  OpenDNS is `208.67.222.222` and is operated by Cisco.  Google and OpenDNS are equivalent when it comes to privacy and speed.

Comment: @Ramhound ah yeah... Cloudflare, not OpenDNS. My bad. Thanks for correcting me.

Answer (score 0):

As per the [OpenDNS page on Huawei routers:](https://support.opendns.com/hc/en-us/articles/228006087-Huawei-Router-Configuration)

> 1. Visit the router's IP address in a new browser window. The standard address of the router's config is 192.168.1.1. (If you have forwarded
>      port 80 to another machine, the location becomes 192.168.1.1:8080.)
> 2. On the left hand panel, click Basic.
> 3. Click DHCP on the expanded menu.

Your primary and secondary DNS servers will be shown on this page.

Comment: That doesn't apply to my system. The DHCP tab doesn't show primary and secondary DNS servers.